# Invalid pk (Model Object) does not exist - Django REST Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I wish to create a Merchant and add Bank account details.

These are my serializers:

```py
class MerchantSerializer(core_serializers.BaseModelSerializer):
    """
    MerchantSerializer
    """
    bank_account_details = serializers.JSONField()
    merchant_entity_id = serializers.UUIDField()

    class Meta:
        model = paylater_models.Merchant
        fields = ('merchant_entity_id', 'bank_account_details',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        create
        :param validated_data:
        :return:
        """

        # with transaction.atomic():
        # Normalizing and separating information
        bank_account_data = validated_data.pop('bank_account_details')
        validated_data.update({'merchant_number': core_utils.generate_alphanumeric_strings()})

        # Creating merchant instance
        instance = super(MerchantSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

        # Creating bank account details for the newly created merchant
        bank_account_data.update({'merchant': instance})
        bank_account_serializer = BankAccountDetailSerializer(data=bank_account_data)
        bank_account_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        bank_account_serializer.save()

        return instance


class BankAccountDetailSerializer(core_serializers.BaseModelSerializer):
    """
    BankAccountDetailSerializer
    """

    bank_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    account_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=18)
    ifsc = serializers.CharField(max_length=11)

    class Meta:
        model = paylater_models.BankAccountDetail
        fields = ('bank_name', 'account_number', 'ifsc', 'merchant',)

    def validate_account_number(self, account_number):
        """
        validate_account_number
        :param bank_name:
        :return:
        """

        if re.search('[0-9]{9,18}', str(account_number)) is not None:
            return account_number

        raise paylater_exceptions.InvalidBankAccountNumberError()

    def validate_ifsc(self, ifsc):
        """
        validate_ifsc
        :param ifsc:
        :return:
        """

        if re.search('[A-Za-z]{4}[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}', ifsc) is not None:
            return ifsc

        raise paylater_exceptions.InvalidIFSCError()
```

It gives me a Invalid pk `\"Merchant object (f7f3f77a-7f18-4a27-ac39-1f182d233006)\"` - object does not exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

I understand that the problem is with the merchant instance that I'm passing to `BankAccountDetailSerializer`, but I don't really know what it is and how to fix this.

Comment: For sure you are making a request to get an object that does not exist. Confirm that the key you are using and corresponding object actually exists in the database.

Comment: Also, it would help if you share a way of replicating the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hey @luistm. A way to replicate the problem is to call the serializer with the data
`
{
 "merchant_entity_id": "0e91bec0-497f-4878-8a3f-ac97383208ff",
 "bank_account_details": {
  "bank_name": "HDFC",
  "account_number": "123456789",
  "ifsc": "HDFC0000123"
 }
}
`
And yes the object exists in the database that's being accessed

Comment: Hi, Sorry, but there is no way I can help you. You should provide the minimum code needed to replicate the problem. I can't even see the BankAccountDetail and i don't have any data to populate it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the above problem provided by @zaphod100.10 is partially correct as in it addresses the basic problem involved within the serializer but there's a bit more to it, which is why I decided to write this answer.

Two takeaways:

1. `merchant.pk` or `merchant.id` is what the `BankAccountDetailSerializer` expects.
2. The field `merchant` on `BankAccountDetailSerializer` needed to be changed to `merchant_id` which now looks like this:

```
class BankAccountDetailSerializer(core_serializers.BaseModelSerializer):
    """
    BankAccountDetailSerializer
    """
    bank_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    account_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=18)
    ifsc = serializers.CharField(max_length=11)
    merchant_id = serializers.UUIDField()

    class Meta:
        model = paylater_models.BankAccountDetail
        fields = ('bank_name', 'account_number', 'ifsc', 'merchant_id',)
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is very simple you have to just use the merchant.pk instead of the merchant object. try this:

`bank_account_data.update({'merchant': instance.pk})`

replace the current line in the merchant serialiser create function with the above line. It should work then.

Remember when you want to supply a related object to the model serializer it should be primary key. Unless you are using nested serializer.